# How to get records if condition is different?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 different table. First is menu and second is category. Category table have one column named menu which is id of table menu(it may be null sometimes). So would like to fetch records and display it. But I am getting number of records than expected.

I have tried this with DISTINCT keyword but still getting same values.

```
$category = DB::select('SELECT 
p.id, p.name, p.sub, p.is_publish, p.created_by, p.updated_by, p.published_by, m.name AS menu 
FROM `product_category` AS p, `menu` AS m 
WHERE p.menu = m.id OR p.menu = 0');
```

Also

```
$category = DB::select('SELECT 
DISTINCT p.id, p.name, p.sub, p.is_publish, p.created_by, p.updated_by, p.published_by, m.name AS menu 
FROM `product_category` AS p, `menu` AS m 
WHERE p.menu = m.id OR p.menu = 0');
```

Now if p.menu is 0 then I should get all values except m.name and if p.menu is not 0 then I should get all the column values.

Comment: or p.menu =0  looks invalid, also menu table should have category id if I understand your design

Comment: No. Category table have column menu which refers menu table id.

Comment: Can you use case inside select statement?I mean that you can use like this : case when p.menu = 0 then '' else p.name end as name